# Is there a way to prevent lots of images from breaking a slideshow in iOS browsers?

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I've been scanning old slides for my folks for a while now, and thought it might be nice to load them up onto a really simple website for them to look at online.

I've figured out the website, using this very basic [Vanilla Slideshow instructions](https://www.cssscript.com/fullscreen-responsive-slideshow-with-vanilla-javascript-and-css3/).

With a few images, it works; if I try to load all 800+ images in, though, it works on desktop but gives me the "Aw, Snap! Something went wrong while displaying this webpage" error in Chrome for iOS, and "A problem repeatedly occurred on (address) in Safari.

Is there a fix, or does it just break after X images?

Comment: I would say it breaks because there are too many pictures to load and process to e.g. set into frame. You might need some custom gallery that will load pictures in page.

Comment: I'll look into that -- thanks.